# Могут ли две визуально разные картинки иметь равный вес?

Tags: изображения

Просто вопрос, даже не знаю, что добавить.

Comment: Вес в байтах? Почему бы и нет

Comment: Картинки размером 1х1 разного цвета визуально разные, а размер одинаков.

Comment: Вот более жизненный пример: [раз](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3hu5.png) и [два](https://cdn.everypony.ru/storage/01/42/24/2019/12/16/34bc422957.jpg) (обе картинки по 23758 байт)

Comment: Более того, бардак дошел до того, что две некартинки тоже могут иметь одинаковый размер. Например, могут иметь одинаковый размер картинка и видео, картинка и аудио, картинка и текст. Вообще, размер файла это некое хэш-значение. Если оно одинаковое, то это ничего не значит. Но зато если оно разное, то значит, что файлы точно разные (в отличие кстати от всяких MD5 и прочих). Этим пользуются при сравнении файлов, если размеры разные, то дальше можно не сравнивать. А если размеры одинаковые, то придется еще сравнивать файлы побайтно. :-)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос ни о чем...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> да в любом можно равный вес сделать при желании.
>   Картинок больше, чем возможных их размеров (с учётом вменяемости размера). Так что существование разных картинок с равным размером предопределено...

Example:

> берите любой несжатый bmp, рисуйте в паинте что хотите и при сохранении вес будет всегда один и тот же